# Ruby on Rails, Datepicker search between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker, ransack

I am a new ROR user trying to implement a DateTime picker to select dates for a search function.

My problem is that when I enter two dates (date from, and date to) in the DatePicker, I get inconsistent results from the search.  Sometimes I get no results, and sometimes I get all the results.  I am also using the `bootstrap-datepicker-rails` gem as well as the `ransack` gem.

This is what my view looks like

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :departure_date_gteq, "Departure Date Between" %>
    <%= f.search_field :departure_date_gteq, "data-provide" => "datepicker" %>
    <%= f.label :return_date_lteq, "and" %>
    <%= f.search_field :return_date_lteq, "data-provide" => "datepicker" %>
  </div>
```

The two database columns I am referencing are departure_date, and return_date. The date stored is datetime and looks like this,

```
departure_date
2016-08-07 00:00:00.000000

return_date
2016-08-14 00:00:00.000000
```

I enter 2016-08-06 and 2016-08-15 in the DatePickers and I am returned all the results.

Could my search form DatePicker be sending data that cannot be correctly compared to the DateTime in the database?

Am I using the 'gteq' and 'lteq' calls correctly?

EDIT #1
@Michael Gaskill, you are correct that the problem is the date formatting. When I enter a date manually, I get the correct search results. I just need to figure out how to correct the formatting before its passed to the controller.

Here is what my controller looks like.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = Sailing.search(params[:q])
    @sailings = @search.result
    ... Other calls ...
  end
end
```

Here is the full piece of code in my view that generates sailings content. Note that I'm using search_for_for which is part of the ransack gem.

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: root_path, method: :post do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :cruise_ship_name_or_cruise_ship_company_or_destination_identifier_cont, "Cruise Ship Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :cruise_ship_name_or_cruise_ship_company_or_destination_identifier_cont %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :departure_date_gteq, "Departure Date Between" %>
            <%= f.search_field :departure_date_gteq, "data-provide" => "datepicker" %>
            <%= f.label :return_date_lteq, "and" %>
            <%= f.search_field :return_date_lteq, "data-provide" => "datepicker" %>
          </div>
          <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
      <% end %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string-formatted dates entered in the form (either via the DatePicker or manually-entered) to Date or DateTime values.  When you query the database, use this `DateTime#strptime` to convert:

```
MyTable.where(date_field_to_search: DateTime.strptime(date_value_from_ui, "%F %T")
```

You can check out the formats available as the second argument to `strptime`, using the instructions at [DateTime:strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).  Note that `strftime` and `strptime` are used to convert back and forth between DateTime and formatted String values.

In your `Sailing#search(params[:q])` example, you can either implement the solution in `Sailing#search` (if you have access to change that code) or prior to calling `Sailing.search`.

Here is how you might implement this in `Sailing#search`:

```
class Sailing
  def search(args)
    datetime = args[:date_field_to_search]
    if datetime.kind_of?(String)
      datetime = DateTime.strptime(datetime, "%F %T")
    end
    # other search functionality
  end
end
```

or, prior to calling `Sailing#search`:

```
datetime = params[:q][:date_field_to_search]
if datetime.kind_of?(String)
  datetime = DateTime.strptime(datetime, "%F %T")
end
Sailing.search(params[:q].merge({ date_field_to_search: datetime })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Here is the query I'm working with.   search = Sailing.search(params[:q])  is my query. I'm passing the data to the view here     sailings = search.result  . Do I need to change the formatting in the controller or the view?

Comment: In the controller.  I updated my answer with a couple of examples of how you would do it related to `Sailing#search`.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for your reply. I can't seem to get it working at the moment, but I'll try again tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: OK.  If you update your question with the actual code that you're working on, I can pitch in and see how I can help get it working.

Comment: Yeah, this alerted me to the fact that the datepicker I was using was formatting my data in a way that wasn't compatible with my search. After changing out the datepicker, I was able to get the intended results. Thanks for your time Michael.

Comment: @Aptorian Awesome! So glad to hear that you were able to get past it.  Good luck!